# How do you make sure the roast chicken and the sides are done at the same time?

Tags: oven, roasting

I often avoid adding sides like rice or potatoes to my roast chicken because my chicken often reaches 165f wayyy before the rice or the potatoes are done. Is there a technique to get both the roast chicken and sides done at the same time?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you add the sides **to** the chicken? Are they in a separate pan?

Comment: @Catija they are both in the pan when I put it in the oven. It's just that the chicken is cooked before the taters

Answer (score 3):

Simply put the sides in before or after the meat for an appropriate length of time such that everything is ready at once.

For example, say my roast chicken takes 1.5 hours to cook including resting. Roast potatoes take 1 hour. Therefore I put my roast potatoes in the oven 0.5 hours after I put the chicken in, and they are both done at the same time.